# Gitolite: how to get user IP address who clone or push to git

Tags: git, gitolite

Let's say I'm administrating a gitolite server. Is it possible to see the IP address of a user who cloned or pushed to my hosted repository? I have a custom `POST_GIT` trigger installed that reads in `.gitolite/logs` but logs don't contain IP addresses.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It might depend on your Gitolite version.

In my `.gitolite/logs` (gitolite 3.5+) , I do see the IP:

```
2014-09-29.07:38:59 19273   ssh ARGV=aUserName   SOC=git-upload-pack 'aRepoName1' FROM=128.20x.xxx.xxx
2014-09-29.07:38:59 19274   ssh ARGV=aUserName   SOC=git-upload-pack 'aRepoName2'   FROM=128.20x.xxx.xxx
```

(also valid for http connections, not just ssh ones)

The [`src/gitolite-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell#L77-L86) does include the IP:

```
gl_log( 'ssh', "ARGV=" . join( ",", @ARGV ), "SOC=" . ( $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND} || '' ), "FROM=$ip" );
```

Introduced/updated in [commit 906ed4c](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/906ed4cbe2a7ddc338b6238cc075d307c82cb882) (for gitolite 3.04+, June 2012)