# How to see ip addresses of computers that pushed or pulled or cloned a remote repo

Tags: git, github

how can we find or list ip addresses of computers that pushed, pulled, committed, or cloned a remote repository in git or github?

I have pulled a repository of my own from my github account and for some reason I need to know the ip address of the computer from which I had pushed this repo-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect IP address of GitHub commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983017/detect-ip-address-of-github-commit)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which version of GitHub you are using and with what privileges.
What you are asking for [isn't a built in Git capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577105/is-it-possible-to-get-info-about-which-ip-or-computer-from-git-commit-history-o).
However if you have access to the server itself then that information is probably logged somewhere.
Examples: [GitHub Enterprise servers](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.21/admin/user-management/viewing-push-logs), or if you use [Gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093734/gitolite-how-to-get-user-ip-address-who-clone-or-push-to-git) or [GitLab](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-find-out-ip-address-of-a-given-push-event/5377).